# Pass data trough Javascript to Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Guys I am trying to pass some data to my typeahead form, but for some reason my code isn't working:

This is my HTML CODE:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" id="getsourCe" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />
```

This is my Javascript Code:

```
<script>  
var programLang = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];   
$('#getsourCe').typeahead({source: programLang})  
</script>
```

The only error I'm getting is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token. 
and I am not even sure its related to the problem. My html code isn't changing at all!

Comment: Just a note: If you're getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError` it's likely to stop other things working so focus on that first.

Comment: already fix that, but nothing is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your JS code in a `$(document).ready`.  You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/EkFQP/

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var programLang = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];   
     $('#getsourCe').typeahead({source: programLang})  
});​
```